# What's the 2023 way of making a HTML section 100vw?

Tags: html, css

In many web designs, the content is "containered" to be centered and max-widthed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
    <div id="container" style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
    
        <section>
            <h1>Containered Content</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </p>
        </section>

        <section style="WHAT GOES HERE?">
            <h2>My background should overflow the container</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </p>
        </section>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to give the 2nd section a "stripe" where the background is `100vw`, how would you do this theses days?

What I am not asking for, is a solution like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <section style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <h1>Containered Content</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum ...
        </p>
    </section>
    
    <section style="background: black;">
        <div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <h2>My background should overflow the container</h2>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum ...
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technique using border-image where you consider a big outset to create the overflow:

```css
.stripe {
  border-image: 
   repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, red 0 10px, blue 0 20px) 
   fill 0//0 50vw;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="max-width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">

  <section>
    <h1>Containered Content</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum ...
    </p>
  </section>

  <section class="stripe">
    <h2>My background should overflow the container</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum ...
    </p>
  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: I like that, but it's not working. Your snippet is not working as well. What is `//0`?

Comment: @JanBoehmer how do you like it if it's not working?

Comment: That would be the solution I'd prefer. Finally, I'd love to see a solution with a solid background, or image.

Comment: @JanBoehmer replace `repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, red 0 10px, blue 0 20px)` with `linear-gradient(red 0 0)` to get a solid background

Comment: Thank you and is it possible to use an image with `background-size: contain` ?

Comment: @JanBoehmer you cannot and all of these requirements aren't mentioned in your question. If you want to get accurate answers, you need to provide clear and complete requirement to avoid us wasting time with useless answers.